# Weird error with opengl in Android using Libgdx : "EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE"

Tags: opengl, android, libgdx

I am having a weird error when uploading my game in the phones.

**E/Adreno200-EGL(5128): qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:484>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE**

I am uploading the textures with AssetManager.

I am using OpenGL 1.0.

It begans to upload the textures, but when it is about to finish uploading them, it finishes unexpectedly without any message in logcat.

Any ideas what is happening?

When I updated my xperia ray to ics it began having this problem

And when it loads, and I navigate through screens I get this in logcat

<**qgl2DrvAPI_glClear:33>: GL_INVALID_VALUE**

**This is my line using the clear**

- this.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

The type of gl is GL10

Although the first error occurs when it is loading :/

Here is my logcat output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official OpenGL documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClear.xml),

> `glClear` generates `GL_INVALID_VALUE` if any bit other than the four defined bits is set in mask.

So, i would double check your `glClear` sentence. Can you post a few of your code so we can check it?

---

**EDIT:** I believe you have more than one error in your code. First, looks like OpenGL ES is complaining about this `glClear` and it is causing a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` gl error. Then, regarding other error, having a look at the OpenGL ES documentation of [eglGetConfigAttrib](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/eglGetConfigAttrib.html), you can see that

> `EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE` is generated if *attribute* is not a valid frame buffer configuration attribute.

Can you post again the line where you use `eglGetConfigAttrib`? I would double check that *`attribute`* parameter and its value.

Comment: I uploaded it :) although I think it is a problem with the update to ICS :/ I have to investigate with the bad logic games people :(

Comment: I doo´t use the eglGetConfigAttrib :/ I think that the libgdx libraries do that